# How to give an absolute position to a table in iTextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I am using a iTextsharp to create a table.I want a table at particular position in the  page and I am using a **table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 300, 300, pcb);** method but its not working. Here is my code.

```
           using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("TableTest.pdf", FileMode.Create))
           {
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            PdfWriter writer =  PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
            doc.Open();
            PdfContentByte pcb = writer.DirectContent;
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(9);
            table.TotalWidth = 595f;

            // Hdeaer row.
            table.AddCell(GetCell("Header 1", 1, 2));
            table.AddCell(GetCell("Header 2", 1, 2));
            table.AddCell(GetCell("Header 3", 5, 1));
            table.AddCell(GetCell("Header 4", 1, 2));
            table.AddCell(GetCell("Header 5", 1, 2));

            // Inner middle row.
            table.AddCell(GetCell("H1"));
            table.AddCell(GetCell("H2"));
            table.AddCell(GetCell("H3"));
            table.AddCell(GetCell("H4"));
            table.AddCell(GetCell("H5"));

            // Bottom row.
            table.AddCell(GetCell("D1"));
            table.AddCell(GetCell("D2"));
            table.AddCell(GetCell("D3"));
            table.AddCell(GetCell("D4"));
            table.AddCell(GetCell("D5"));
            table.AddCell(GetCell("D6"));
            table.AddCell(GetCell("D7"));
            table.AddCell(GetCell("D8"));
            table.AddCell(GetCell("D9"));
            table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 300, 300, pcb);
            doc.Close();
   }
   private PdfPCell GetCell(string text)
    {
        return GetCell(text, 1, 1);
    }
    private PdfPCell GetCell(string text, int colSpan, int rowSpan)
    {
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(text));
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        cell.Rowspan = rowSpan;
        cell.Colspan = colSpan;

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Does the answer help? If not, please point out the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You try to write the table before you've added any content to the table. It is normal that nothing is shown on the page. Move `writeSelectedRows()` down in your code:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(9);
table.TotalWidth = 595;

// there isn't any content in the table: there's nothing to write yet

// Header row.
table.AddCell(GetCell("Header 1", 1, 2));
table.AddCell(GetCell("Header 2", 1, 2));
table.AddCell(GetCell("Header 3", 5, 1));
table.AddCell(GetCell("Header 4", 1, 2));
table.AddCell(GetCell("Header 5", 1, 2));

// Inner middle row.
table.AddCell(GetCell("H1"));
table.AddCell(GetCell("H2"));
table.AddCell(GetCell("H3"));
table.AddCell(GetCell("H4"));
table.AddCell(GetCell("H5"));

// Now we've added 2 rows: two rows will be shown:

table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 300, 300, pcb);
```

Note that I've changed the number of columns in the table, because you're only adding 5 rows for the first row, and five rows for the second row. Note that *incomplete rows aren't rendered*, so that may be another reason why your code doesn't do what you expect.

Finally you should remove:

```
doc.Add(table);
```

This adds the table at the current position of the cursor in the page. That's probably not where you want it.

Comment: *Its does not working* is not a question. You should explain *the expected behavior* and describe *the resulting behavior* otherwise nobody knows what you mean when you say "it doesn't work". See also http://lowagie.com/doesntwork

Comment: *Note that I've changed the number of columns in the table, because you're only adding 5 rows for the first row, and five rows for the second row.* - the OP's method `GetCell(string text, int colSpan, int rowSpan)` actually makes the table use 9 columns, doesn't it?

Comment: Aha, I didn't see those methods when I first answered the question. Were they added afterwards?

Comment: @sai Changing the question after it's answered isn't really nice. Also: you are still adding the table twice. Remove `doc.Add(table)`!

Comment: @sai If you say "it doesn't work" because the table is added twice, then you are wrong. It *does* work the way you coded it: you add the table twice in your code.

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie sorry sir  it was my mistake of editing a question once it answered.

Answer (score 1):

You say *its not working* but did not explain what isn't working.

Thus, I ran your program to compare the output with your code. The result:

[image: Output of OP's code]

Considering that your code explicitly positions a table as wide as an A4 page

```
table.TotalWidth = 595f;
```

at a position horizontally located in mid page

```
table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 300, 300, pcb);
```

this exactly is what was to be expected. Thus, *it is working*!

---

If your original intention was to have the table start horizontally at mid-page and extend to the right page border, you should have set the table width to the page width *minus your center x*, i.e.

```
table.TotalWidth = 295f;
```

If on the other hand you wanted the table start at the left page border and extend to the right one, you should have position at x = 0:

```
table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, 300, pcb);
```