# How to use WriteSelectedRows in iTextSharp PDF?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am working on a program which automatically generates invoices. I want to add table at specific position always(e.g. at bottom corner, or slightly to the left).

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.TotalWidth = 400f;
table.AddCell("Test");
table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 200, 50, cb);
```

I got the above code on Google. But I couldn't understand how to use `WriteSelectedRows` and what each number in the bracket meant for.

I expect the output code to be such that I could place my table anywhere I want on the page.

Can someone explain me the exact usage of this function?

Comment: Please don't add "don't mark this as duplicate" banners to your questions. Instead, link to the questions you found and explain what exactly you didn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values mean, [according to the documentation](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/iTextSharp.text.pdf/PdfPTable/WriteSelectedRows/php-pdfptable-writeselectedrows-method-examples.html):

- rowStart  int
- rowEnd    int
- xPos  float
- yPos  float

By using rowStart = 0 and rowEnd = -1, you indicate you want to write all rows. The parameters after that indicate the absolute position where to render the table, in your case 200 pixels from the left and 50 pixels from the top.

See also:
* [itextsharp: what is the height of a regular PDF page in pixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910881/itextsharp-what-is-the-height-of-a-regular-pdf-page-in-pixels)
* [How to give an absolute position to a table in iTextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223020/how-to-give-an-absolute-position-to-a-table-in-itextsharp)